# Convert function to linq statment

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, linq-to-sql

I have three tables in my database `Subscriber`, `Subscription` and `Branch`.
Each `Subscriber` can have one `Subscription` in a specified `Branch`.
I want to list all subscribers which have no subscription in a defined branch. For this purpose I wrote below function but I know it can be written more shortly and efficiently using LINQ operators but I have not enough knowledge to do this.

Can you change this function to a LINQ statement?

```
List<Subscriber> subscribersWithNoSubscriptinoInThisBranch(int branchId)
{
    DbSet<Subscriber> allSubscribers = db.Subscriber;
    List<Subscriber> subscribers = new List<Subscriber>();
    foreach (Subscriber s in db.Subscriber)
    {
        ICollection<Subscription> subscriptions = s.Subscription;
        if (subscriptions.Where(su => su.branchId == branchId).Count() == 0)
        {
            subscribers.Add(s);
        }
    }
    return subscribers;
}
```

Comment: How did you identify if above code is less efficient compared to a LINQ one?

Comment: @Lucifer This does one query for all subscribers, then does one query for each subscriber to get the count of subscriptions which is way less efficient than one query to do all of it on the DB.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the following is what you want:

```
List<Subscriber> subscribers = allSubscribers
    .Where(s => !s.Subscription.Any(su => su.branchId == branchId))
    .ToList();
```

Comment: It depends on what you want to achieve. If you're not done with filtering yet you should not take the results in memory with a ToList. If this is the final result then yes add a ToList

Comment: This one lists all subscribers which have subscription in specified branch. I want those who have **not** subscriptions.

Comment: I think OP wants the inverse of that, "*subscribers which have no subscription in a defined branch*"

Comment: I will change it to !s.Subscription.Any(..)